# dynamically remove td from table inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, ado.net

I have a situation in which i have to show data in following manner.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| header 1               |        header 2         |         header 3        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Subheader1 |Subheader2 | Subheader1 | Subheader2 | Subheader1 | Subheader2 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Data       |   Data    |    Data    |   Data     |   Data     |    Data    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i have used gridview to present data in the above manner. In the following way i have 
written gridview code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridt" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">            
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                <table border="1" style="text-align:center" >
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Header 1
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Header 2
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Header 3
                                        </td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <td style="width:75px">
                                            Subheader1
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width:75px">
                                            Subheader2
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width:75px">
                                            Subheader1
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width:75px">
                                            Subheader2
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width:75px">
                                            Subheader1
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width:75px">
                                            Subheader2
                                        </td> 
                                       </tr>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                     <ItemTemplate>                        
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width:75px">
                                            <%# Eval("xxx")%>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width:75px">
                                            <%# Eval("xxx1")%>
                                        </td>

                                        <td style="width:75px" >
                                            <%# Eval("yyy")%>
                                        </td>

                                        <td style="width:75px">
                                            <%# Eval("yyy1")%>
                                        </td>

                                        <td style="width:75px">
                                            <%# Eval("zzz")%>
                                        </td>

                                        <td style="width:75px">
                                            <%# Eval("zzz1")%> 
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                              </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Now i want to dynamically remove header 2 along with subheader 1, subheader2 and data.
Please suggest something..

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign class / id to the cell that you want to make  hidden , and use jQuery  or javascript to implement this.
you may call this function whereas you need page as well as code behind

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign class / id to the cell that you want to make hidden , and use jQuery or javascript to implement this. you may call this function whereas you need page as well as code behind

then use jquery

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

or

```
$(this).remove();
```

based on ur requirement...